# Different Menu on a specific Page

Tags: wordpress, function, header-files, menuitem

I have a Page on my WordPress website called "**CordialTech**".

When on this Page, I want to show a different Header Menu.

I know of a plugin called "Conditional Menu" that achieves this.

But I want to achieve this with PHP Code inserted in my functions.php of my Child Theme.

What code can I use for this?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code. Let me know if you need any help with this code to understand.

```
function my_wp_nav_menu_args( $args ) {
    if ( is_page( 'Sample Page' ) ) { // page name/slug
        $args['menu'] = 'Other Menu'; // menu name/slug
    } else {
        $args['menu'] = 'Prymary'; // menu name/slug
    }
    
    return $args;
}

add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', 'my_wp_nav_menu_args' );
```

Comment: Thank You very much Sir for this code. 

It worked perfectly. I'm really very grateful.

Thanks so much.